# Exchange Web Services: Batching with FindItemsResult<Item>

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm writing an app to process email attachments, using Exchange Web Services.

The general structure of my problem area is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = FindItems();

    foreach (Item item in findResults)
    {
        DoSomethingWithItem(item);
    }
}

public static FindItemsResults<Item> FindItems()
{
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

            ItemView view = new ItemView(10);    //batching 10 at a time
            view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
                BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                ItemSchema.Subject,
                ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);

            findResults = service.FindItems(
                WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                    LogicalOperator.Or,
                    new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, Properties.Settings.Default.EmailSubject)),
                view);

            //return set of emails
            return findResults;
}
```

At first, this looked OK - it processed my earlier test examples perfectly well. But when I start testing with bulk loads, I realised that it was only processing the first 10 items, since I was specifying a batch size of 10 items (`ItemView view = new ItemView(10`)), but I wasn't checking for further batches.

I could have simply increased the batch size, but a quick google later, I found a better example:

```
public static FindItemsResults<Item> FindItems()
{
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

            ItemView view = new ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning); 
            view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);
            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
                BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                ItemSchema.Subject,
                ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);

            do
            {
                findResults = service.FindItems(
                    WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                    new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                        LogicalOperator.Or,
                        new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, Properties.Settings.Default.EmailSubject)),
                    view);

                //any more batches?
                if (findResults.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
                {
                    view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset.Value;
                }
            }
            while (findResults.MoreAvailable);

            return findResults;
}
```

This loops through as many emails as I care to throw at it, but for reasons I can't yet understand, the foreach loop now only processes the first item in findResults.

Even though findResults contains more than one item (`findResults.Items.Count` > 1), with my second example, `findResults.MoreAvailable` = false. Fair enough, I've looped through the batches earlier, so it makes sense that I'm looking at the end of the last batch.

But how do I reset findResults so that it will process the whole lot? I tried setting findResults.MoreAvailable but it is readonly... What am I missing?

**CONCLUSION:**

OK, so I can either process the items one batch at a time, or I can add each item in each batch to a List and process them later, as I currently do.

There is not a lot between them; I've initially started using a List, but I'll consider the choice further.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to my that your main problem is that you try define a function which returns `FindItemsResults<Item>`. If you use paring of results you will have **not one** object of this type. Instead of that on retrieving of every new page the `FindItemsResults<Item>` will be overwritten. Following example display subjects of all items from the `Inbox`:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
    BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
    ItemSchema.Subject,
    ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);

// save the folder where we will make searching to do this one time
Folder myInbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

do
{
    findResults = myInbox.FindItems(
        new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject,
                Properties.Settings.Default.EmailSubject)),
        view);

    foreach (Item item in findResults)
    {
        // Do something with the item.
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (item is EmailMessage)
        {
            EmailMessage em = item as EmailMessage;
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: \"{0}\"", em.Subject);
        }
        else if (item is MeetingRequest)
        {
            MeetingRequest mr = item as MeetingRequest;
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: \"{0}\"", mr.Subject);
        }
        else
        {
            // we can handle other item types
        }
    }

    //any more batches?
    if (findResults.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
    {
        view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset.Value;
    }
}
while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

The code display the subjects on the console output. If you want to use `EmailMessage` or `MeetingRequest` in another way you should modify the code correspondent. You can also define a delegate which do something with the found `EmailMessage` or `MeetingRequest` and call the delegate on the place of `Console.WriteLine`. If you do need to same all items somewhere, then you will have to create some collection like `List<Item>`, fill there in the function and return instead of `FindItemsResults<Item>` which you currently do.